# Splitting of central simple algebras in the Schur subgroup over residue fields of places

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, brauer-groups, central-simple-algebras

​Recall that a *valuation domain* of ​a field extension ​$K/k$ is a $k$-subalgebra $V$ of $K$ ​not equal to $K$ ​such that for every $a\in K$ at least one of $a$ and $a^{-1}$ is in $V$.
A​ ​*place* of $K/k$ is ​a​ residue field of a valuation domain of $K/k$​, which will again be an extension of $k$.

Now let $G$ be a finite group and $\chi$ a character of an irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $G$. The field $k:= \mathbb{Q}(\chi)$ of character values is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\chi$ corresponds to a unique simple component $A_k$ of the group ring $kG$, which will be a central simple algebra with center $k$.

> **Example 1.** If $G$ is the quaternion group $Q_8$ and $\chi$ is the
> character of the unique two-dimensional irreducible
> $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $G$, then $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and
> $A_k=\mathbb{H}$, the quaternions.

We now consider a finitely generated field extension $K/k$ together with a place $L/k$. We obtain from the central simple algebra $A_k$ central simple algebras $A_K:=A_k\otimes_k K$ and $A_L:=A_k\otimes_k L$ with centers $K$ and $L$, respectively, which define elements of the Schur subgroups of the Brauer groups of $K$ and $L$.

​Since the splitting behavior of central simple algebras is governed by generalized Brauer-Severi varieties, which admit a point over the place $L$ if they have a point over $K$, the Schur index of $A_L$ is at most as large as that of $A_K$. In particular, we have that $A_L$ splits whenever $A_K$ splits.

> **Example 2.** Consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(x, y | x^2+y^2=-1)$ with $k=\mathbb{Q}$. With $A_k=\mathbb{H}$, we get that $A_K$, and hence every $A_L$ splits.
>
> **Example 3.** Consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(x, y)$ with $k=\mathbb{Q}$. With $A_k=\mathbb{H}$, we get that $A_K$ does not split. Over "most" places $L/k$ of $K/k$, namely precisely those in which $x^2+y^2=-1$ does not admit a solution, the central simple algebra $A_L$ will not split.

This leads to the following question:

> **Question** Is there always a place $L/k$ of $K/k$ such that $A_L$ and $A_K$ have the same Schur index?​

I know that the answer to the more general question with arbitrary $k$ instead of a finite abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and no restriction to the Schur subgroup is negative. If $K$ is the function field of a surface and $k=\mathbb{C}$, then by Tsen's theorem the Brauer groups of places of $K/k$ will all be trivial, hence any such $K$ with non-trivial Brauer group will provide a counterexample.